# HTML file input on iOS - accept images and videos

Tags: html, ios9

I want to implement a HTML file input to let the user shoot a picture or a video. I define the allowed formats via `accept` attribute:

```
<input type="file" id="sentFile" accept="image/*,video/*">
```

If I click on the input, iOS 9 shows me a modal, where I'm able to "Record picture or video". After clicking on that button, the camera app opens and I'm able to take a picture, but can't record a video.

If I define a single input with video only, f.e.:

```
<input type="file" id="sentFile" accept="video/*">
```

I'm able to record a video.

Why is the first one not working on iOS?

Comment: Just tested it on my iPhone 7, IOS 10.3.1 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

try this
`accept="image/*;video/*;capture=camcorder"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` in your ios application?

You need to add that permission if you want to take a photo in your application.